# Different Definitions for Solvable Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, solvable-groups

Dummit and Footes definition of solvable groups is

> $G$ has a chain of subgroups: $1=N_0\trianglelefteq N_1 \trianglelefteq N_2 \trianglelefteq \dots \trianglelefteq N_t = G$ such that each $N_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $N_{i+1}/N$ is abelian, $0\le i\le t-1$

Wikipedia has the same definition and then adds,

> For finite groups, an equivalent definition is that a solvable group is a group with a composition series all of whose factors are cyclic groups of prime order. This is equivalent because a finite group has finite composition length, and every simple abelian group is cyclic of prime order.

I don't understand how these are equivalent. Since composition series have simple factors, is this saying *every* abelian group is simple?

Comment: No. Since the subgroup of an abelian group is always normal, an abelian group is simple whenever they are cyclic prime ordered groups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No: the composition series described in the second definition is not necessarily the same as the chain of subgroups described in the first definition.  Rather, you obtain the composition series by *refining* the chain (adding more intermediate groups in between).  As a sketch of how to do this, since $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is abelian, it has a composition series where all the factors are cyclic of prime order.  We can now lift all the subgroups of $N_{i+1}/N_i$ in that composition series up to subgroups of $N_{i+1}$ which contain $N_i$, and insert them into our chain of subgroups in between $N_i$ and $N_{i+1}$.  Doing this for each $i$, we refine the original chain of subgroups into a longer one in which the factors are not just abelian but cyclic of prime order.